# « Langage musclé » : sens

Tags: sens, expressions, expressions-idiomatiques

J'ai récemment découvert une expression qui défie ma compréhension ; j'ai eu beau passer en revue des extraits la contenant et faire de la recherche, je ne suis pas arrivé à déterminer sons sens ; c'est cependant un syntagme défini : "*langage musclé*". On ne le trouve pas dans le TLFi ([langage](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/langage), [musclé](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/muscl%C3%A9)).

Voici deux exemples de son utilisation.

- ([ré. 1](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Le_moment_68_et_la_r%C3%A9invention_de_l_Aca/bAGEBAAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22langage+muscl%C3%A9%22&pg=PA183&printsec=frontcover)) La glorification de l'État providence, durant toute la première moitié des Trente Glorieuses, avait aussi créé de très grandes attentes, tout comme le langage musclé de la Révolution tranquille au Québec.
- ([réf. 2](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Newjack_Dans_la_peau_d_un_gardien_de_pri/wlpTDwAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22langage+muscl%C3%A9%22&pg=PT42&printsec=frontcover)) Ils marchaient nonchalamment et employaient un langage musclé ; ils nous expliquèrent que c'étaient les tribunaux qui imposaient l'heure de promenade quotidienne.

On trouve un grand nombre d'exemples de son utilisation [ici](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22langage%20muscl%C3%A9%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr).

Comment: *Musclé* veut dire énergique, autoritaire..., et on emploie cet adjectif pour bien d'autres choses que le langage (rapports, une direction, un gouvernement, une déclaration etc.) et je personnellement ne ressens pas « langage musclé » comme un syntagme plus défini que l'emploi de cet adjectif avec tout autre nom abstrait. Un langage musclé c'est un langage énergique et/ou autoritaire. On a pas mal employé l'adjectif pour parler des discours d'un certain président désormais déchu...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Musclé veut dire énergique, autoritaire..., et on emploie cet adjectif pour bien d'autres choses que le langage (rapports, une direction, un gouvernement, une déclaration etc.) et je personnellement ne ressens pas « langage musclé » comme un syntagme plus défini que l'emploi de cet adjectif avec tout autre nom abstrait.

Un langage musclé c'est un langage énergique et/ou autoritaire. On a pas mal employé l'adjectif pour parler des discours d'un certain président désormais déchu...